# Не отображается дата и автор в django проекте

Tags: python, django

В общем по ходу исправления, отображение автора на странице и дата публикации поста перестала отображаться, смотри на скрине.
models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст')
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(
    User,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='posts',
    verbose_name='Автор'
)
group = models.ForeignKey(
    Group,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    verbose_name='Группа',
    related_name='posts'
)
```

html шаблон поста

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% for post in page_obj %}
<article>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Автор: {{ post.author.get_full_name }}
    </li>
    <li>
      Дата публикации: {{ pub_date|date:"d E Y" }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  {% thumbnail post.image "960x339" crop="center" upscale=True as im %}
    <img class="card-img my-2" src="{{ im.url }}">
  {% endthumbnail %}
  <p>  {{ post.text }}  </p>    
  {% if post.group %}   
    <a href="{% url 'posts:group_list' post.group.slug %}"> 
      все записи группы
    </a>
  {% endif %} 
  {% if not forloop.last %}<hr>{% endif %}
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

[image: отсутствует автор и дата]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте код в шаблоне
у Вас так:

```
{{ pub_date|date:"d E Y" }}
```

А надо:

```
{{post.pub_date|date:"d E Y" }}
```

Что касается автора, в таблице `User` нет данных `first_name` и `last_name` из которых метод `get_full_name` строит строку

Поля `first_name` и `last_name` являются необязательными к заполнению в [User](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py)

```
first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
```

Comment: С датой понятно, а что насчёт автора?

Comment: @andreymal модель User не переопределялась?

Comment: Да, дату почему-то исправлял как posts отсюда и не получалось, спасибо, а вот что с автором?

Comment: @Vlados User обычная User = get_user_model()

Comment: @Nikita у User нет данных first_name и last_name

Comment: @Vlados, так, а раньше было, куда копать?

Comment: @Nikita гляньте поля БД User и добавьте нужные через админ-панель